# Return only max value from one column when all other columns are the same

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, greatest-n-per-group, row-number

I have a Snowflake query that currently outputs results as follows:

| ID | City | Fruit | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | LA | Banana | 1 |
| 123 | LA | Strawberry | 1 |
| 124 | LA | Banana | 3 |
| 125 | NY | Apple | 2 |

I would like it to return only one ID line containing the max value of the fruit, so in this case, it would look like:

| ID | City | Fruit | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | LA | Strawberry | 1 |
| 124 | LA | Banana | 3 |
| 125 | NY | Apple | 2 |

I have tried doing ROW_NUMBER() OVER Partition but it only ends up selecting rows that don't have two identical IDs, I have tried select distinct but it doesn't choose distinct values for Fruit, and I have tried select max(Fruit) but I get an error saying that it's not a valid group by expression.

Comment: You may want to start here: https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/how-to-select-the-top-n-rows-per-group-with-sql-in-oracle-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
select ID, City, Fruit, Quantity FROM TestData
    QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by ID, City order by Fruit DESC ) = 1;

+-----+------+------------+----------+
| ID  | CITY |   FRUIT    | QUANTITY |
+-----+------+------------+----------+
| 123 | LA   | Strawberry |        1 |
| 124 | LA   | Banana     |        3 |
| 125 | NY   | Apple      |        2 |
+-----+------+------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

We can start using `MAX` and `GROUP BY` to fetch the id and their maximum fruit:

```
SELECT id, MAX (fruit) AS fruit
FROM fruits
GROUP BY id;
```

This can be used as subquery to also select the other columns for these rows:

```
SELECT id, city, fruit, quantity
FROM fruits
WHERE (id, fruit)
IN 
  (SELECT id,
  MAX (fruit) AS fruit
  FROM fruits
  GROUP BY id);
```

If it's really intended to group by the other columns, too (which seems strange to me, but maybe this is wanted), we can just extend this:

```
SELECT id, city, fruit, quantity
FROM fruits
WHERE (id, city, fruit, quantity)
IN (SELECT id, city,
       MAX (fruit) AS fruit,
       quantity
FROM   fruits
GROUP  BY id, city, quantity);
```

For the sample data in the question, both queries will give the same result:

| ID | City | Fruit | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | LA | Strawberry | 1 |
| 124 | LA | Banana | 3 |
| 125 | NY | Apple | 2 |

Try out here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9ThdSZnT)